# How to extract initials from name in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract initials from user names and next replace names with initials

```py
s = pd.DataFrame(['Robert Flitz', 'Hans Malek', 'Marek J. Beer'])
```

when i try use this function

```py
def initials(name):
    init = ""
    for n in name.str.split():
        for i in n:
            init+=i[0]
    return init
```

it returns single string

```
initials(s[0])
'RFHMMJB'
```

I want to look it like

```
'RF'
'HM'
'MJB'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use a regular expression:

```
s[0].str.replace('[^A-Z]', '')
0     RF
1     HM
2    MJB
```

Comment: Regex is usually very fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
s[0].apply(lambda x: ''.join(i[0] for i in x.split()))
```

Output:

```
0    RF
1    HM
2    MJB
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Change it numpy array

```
np.array(s[0].apply(lambda x: ''.join(i[0] for i in x.split())))
```

Output:

```
array(['RF', 'HM', 'MJB'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your initials function. Append a new line to the *`init`* variable after the end of the inner loop.

```
def initials(name):
    init = ""
    for n in name.str.split():
        for i in n:
            init+=i[0]
        init+= "\n"
    return init
```

Answer (score 0):

A more `pandas` approach would probably be:

```
def initials(name):
    init = ""
    for n in name.split():
        init+=n[0]
    return init
s[1] = s[0].apply(initials)
```

this gives:

```
               0    1
0   Robert Flitz   RF
1     Hans Malek   HM
2  Marek J. Beer  MJB
```

You can then get a list of initials with `list(s[1])` if you need it in that format.